# Angular: Using ui-view in multiple places

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use UI-router and `ui-view` to inject my content into my page. But I've stumbled across a tricky scenario that I'm not sure how to handle.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="fixed">
    <nav><\nav>
    <ul class="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"><\li>
    <\ul>
<\div>

<div ui-view><\div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the `items` in the `ng-repeat` don't render outside of the `ui-view`, and I don't want to put my `ui-view` inside of the `.fixed` div, as I'd have to close that `.fixed` div in every view template, and the HTML begins to get real messy at that point.

Are there any better ways to handle this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So long as `.fixed` is under a scope / controller that defined `items`, it should render fine. Also, your end tags are wrong - it should be `</div>`, not `<\div>`

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try. Sorry about the closing divs, trying to write html on an iPhone is horrible.